# Textos não aparecem nem mesmo no botão

Tags: android-studio

Boa Tarde!

tenho o seguinte `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".Principal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
           android:width="200dp"
           android:textAlignment="center"
           tools:text="Logon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLogin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                tools:text="Login" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSenha"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                tools:text="Senha" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtLogin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtSenha"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            tools:text="Logar" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

E o **código** java correspondente:

```
package carcleo.com.cadastro;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Principal extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.principal);
    }
}
```

E o seguinte layout foi gerado no `Android Studio.`

Acontece que quando compilo no `device` (Moto G 4 Play), não aparece nenhum `TextView` nem mesmo **o texto do botão**.

Onde estou errando?

Segue imagem do form no `Android Studio`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No device, as palavras

Logon,
Login,
Senha,
LOGAR

Não aparecem.

Mas parece que os elementos estão lá ocupando o espaço.

Comment: No device não tem nenhuma configuração de idioma?

Comment: Como assim?
Está configurado português Brasil. 
Mas, perdoe-me a dúvida: Como isso pode influenciar se é apenas um rótulo de texto?

Comment: Era apenas uma especulação, você poderia ter alguma configuração na sua aplicação que pegaria o idioma do device. Caso o idioma setado no device não tivesse nada referenciado na aplicação, as informações apareceriam em branco. De novo, era apenas uma especulação.

Comment: Ah! Obg. Esse projeto só tem mesmo essa tela, Nada mais, Estou no b.a.bá do Android.

Comment: Altera o tools:text, por android:text="example"